# How to access elements of a JArray (or iterate over them)

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, json.net

I have the following Json gotten from Twitter

```
     +      token   {[
  {
    "trends": [
      {
        "name": "Croke Park II",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Croke+Park+II%22",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%22Croke+Park+II%22",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#twiznight",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23twiznight",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23twiznight",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#Phanhattan",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Phanhattan",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23Phanhattan",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#VinB",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23VinB",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23VinB",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#Boston",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Boston",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23Boston",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#rtept",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23rtept",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23rtept",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Facebook",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Facebook",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Facebook",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Ireland",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Ireland",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Ireland",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Everton",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Everton",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Everton",
        "events": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Twitter",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Twitter",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Twitter",
        "events": null
      }
    ],
    "as_of": "2013-04-17T13:05:30Z",
    "created_at": "2013-04-17T12:51:41Z",
    "locations": [
      {
        "name": "Dublin",
        "woeid": 560743
      }
    ]
  }
]}  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray}
```

Problem is I can't seem to access any of the elements. I have tried foreach loops and normal for loops and can never seem to access individual elemets it always ends up accessing the whole area.

Any idea how I access the individual elements in this Json JArray?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Update - I verified the below works.  Maybe the creation of your JArray isn't quite right.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestJson()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{""trends"": [
              {
                ""name"": ""Croke Park II"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Croke+Park+II%22"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%22Croke+Park+II%22"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""Siptu"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=Siptu"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""Siptu"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""#HNCJ"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%23HNCJ"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%23HNCJ"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""Boston"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=Boston"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""Boston"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""#prayforboston"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%23prayforboston"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%23prayforboston"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""#TheMrsCarterShow"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TheMrsCarterShow"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%23TheMrsCarterShow"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""#Raw"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Raw"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%23Raw"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""Iran"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=Iran"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""Iran"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""#gaa"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%23gaa"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""gaa"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""Facebook"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=Facebook"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""Facebook"",
                ""events"": null
              }]}";

        var twitterObject = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
        var trendsArray = twitterObject.Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "trends").Value;


        foreach (var item in trendsArray.Children())
        {
            var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
            //you could do a foreach or a linq here depending on what you need to do exactly with the value
            var myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "url");
            var myElementValue = myElement.Value; ////This is a JValue type
        }
    }
```

So call Children on your JArray to get each JObject in JArray.  Call Children on each JObject to access the objects properties.

```
foreach(var item in yourJArray.Children())
{
    var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
    //you could do a foreach or a linq here depending on what you need to do exactly with the value
    var myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "url");
    var myElementValue = myElement.Value; ////This is a JValue type
}
```

Comment: Think I have the general idea of what your saying. However if I run this code i eventually get a null reference to myElementValue. Alternatively if i do a foreach loop on myElement the json structure remains the same and im still faced with multiple elements. It's as if the array itself is malformed or something because it refuses to be iterated through.

Comment: See my updated question, shows exactly what I get when I parse the response as a JArray

Comment: Try parsing the json string response as JToken rather than JArray.

Comment: Updated the output now of the JToken parse. Doesn't quite match up to your String

Answer (score 94):

There is a much **simpler** solution for that.
Just treat the items of the `JArray` as `JObject`.

Let's say we have such array of JSON objects:

```
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(@"[
              {
                ""name"": ""Croke Park II"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Croke+Park+II%22"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""%22Croke+Park+II%22"",
                ""events"": null
              },
              {
                ""name"": ""Siptu"",
                ""url"": ""http://twitter.com/search?q=Siptu"",
                ""promoted_content"": null,
                ""query"": ""Siptu"",
                ""events"": null
              }]");
```

To get access each item just do the following:

```
foreach (JObject item in jArray) // <-- Note that here we used JObject instead of usual JProperty
{
    string name = item.GetValue("name").ToString();
    string url = item.GetValue("url").ToString();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually the most straightforward answer I've seen in 3 posts

Comment: @deeps, It might be the parameter you've passed to the GetValue() is incorrect. Could you please provide more details for your case?

Comment: @Just Shadow thanks it was my bad. it works fine now.

Answer (score 10):

Once you have a JArray you can treat it just like any other Enumerable object,
    and using linq you can access them, check them, verify them, and select them.

```
var str = @"[1, 2, 3]";
var jArray = JArray.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", jArray.Where(i => (int)i > 1).Select(i => i.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void ConvertToJArray(object headers)
{
    //where headers is your Twitter response
    JObject JObj = (JObject)headers;//Parse to JObject
    JArray JArr = (JArray)JObj["trends"];//Get the trends array as JArray
    for (int i = 0; i < JArr.Count; i++)
    {
        var Name = JArr[i]["name"].ToString();
        var URL = JArr[i]["url"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.