# getting objects out of a Jarray using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I cant seem to get the data out of a Jarray. Here's my data

```
[{
"CRASH_CONFIGURATION": {
    "hardKeyboardHidden": "HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES",
    "orientation": "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT",
    "keyboard": "KEYBOARD_NOKEYS",
    "screenLayout": "SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL+SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO",
    "mcc": 310,
    "textLayoutDirection": 0,
    "locale": "en_US",
    "compatScreenHeightDp": 455,
    "compatSmallestScreenWidthDp": 320,
    "fontScale": "1.0",
    "navigationHidden": "NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES",
    "screenWidthDp": 320,
    "fontTypeIndex": "-1",
    "screenHeightDp": 455,
    "uiMode": "UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL+UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO",
    "userSetLocale": false,
    "navigation": "NAVIGATION_NONAV",
    "smallestScreenWidthDp": 320,
    "keyboardHidden": "KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO",
    "seq": 4,
    "mnc": 410,
    "compatScreenWidthDp": 320,
    "touchscreen": "TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER"
},
"USER_CRASH_DATE": "2013-11-01T16:51:01.000-07:00",
"EVENTSLOG": "11-01 16:48:22.499 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1096405040,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:48:36.229 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1096742288,com.android.defcontainer\\/.DefaultContainerService,,19270]\\n11-01 16:48:37.509 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1105265496,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:48:37.539 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1105265496,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:48:43.929 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1105596072,com.google.android.partnersetup\\/.AppInstalledService,dat=package:com.caseglobal.guardcommand,19092]\\n11-01 16:48:43.959 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1105596072,com.google.android.partnersetup\\/.AppInstalledService,19092]\\n11-01 16:48:44.179 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1104414648,com.google.android.apps.plus\\/.service.PackagesMediaMonitor$AsyncService,act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.caseglobal.guardcommand,1168]\\n11-01 16:48:44.189 I\\/binder_sample( 1168): [android.app.IActivityManager,34,117,com.google.android.apps.plus,23]\\n11-01 16:48:44.229 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1104414648,com.google.android.apps.plus\\/.service.PackagesMediaMonitor$AsyncService,1168]\\n11-01 16:48:44.449 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1105669464,com.google.android.talk\\/com.google.android.apps.babel.realtimechat.RealTimeChatService,,5354]\\n11-01 16:48:44.469 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1104067400,com.google.android.gms\\/.games.service.GamesIntentService,act=com.google.android.gms.games.service.INTENT,782]\\n11-01 16:48:44.479 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1105669464,com.google.android.talk\\/com.google.android.apps.babel.realtimechat.RealTimeChatService,5354]\\n11-01 16:48:44.539 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1103009440,com.google.android.gms\\/.people.service.bg.PeopleBackgroundTasks,,782]\\n11-01 16:48:44.549 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1104067400,com.google.android.gms\\/.games.service.GamesIntentService,782]\\n11-01 16:48:44.569 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1103009440,com.google.android.gms\\/.people.service.bg.PeopleBackgroundTasks,782]\\n11-01 16:48:45.449 I\\/am_create_task(  375): 17\\n11-01 16:48:45.449 I\\/am_create_activity(  375): [1095772464,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen,android.intent.action.MAIN,NULL,NULL,268435456]\\n11-01 16:48:45.509 I\\/am_pause_activity(  375): [1102464248,com.lge.launcher2\\/.Launcher]\\n11-01 16:48:45.509 I\\/am_on_paused_called(  624): com.lge.launcher2.Launcher\\n11-01 16:48:45.579 I\\/am_proc_start(  375): [19765,10068,com.caseglobal.guardcommand,activity,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen]\\n11-01 16:48:45.609 I\\/am_proc_bound(  375): [19765,com.caseglobal.guardcommand]\\n11-01 16:48:45.609 I\\/am_restart_activity(  375): [1095772464,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen]\\n11-01 16:48:45.949 I\\/am_create_activity(  375): [1098333256,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen,NULL,NULL,NULL,0]\\n11-01 16:48:45.959 I\\/am_pause_activity(  375): [1095772464,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen]\\n11-01 16:48:45.959 I\\/am_on_resume_called(19765): com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen\\n11-01 16:48:45.959 I\\/am_on_paused_called(19765): com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen\\n11-01 16:48:45.959 I\\/am_restart_activity(  375): [1098333256,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen]\\n11-01 16:48:46.059 I\\/am_on_resume_called(19765): com.caseglobal.guardcommand.ACT_LoginScreen\\n11-01 16:48:46.139 I\\/content_update_sample(19165): [content:\\/\\/com.lge.mlt.main\\/t307,insert,,165,,34]\\n11-01 16:48:46.269 I\\/activity_launch_time(  375): [1098333256,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen,309,753]\\n11-01 16:48:46.329 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1096742288,com.android.defcontainer\\/.DefaultContainerService,19270]\\n11-01 16:48:52.539 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1104415000,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:48:52.559 I\\/force_gc(  375): Binder\\n11-01 16:48:52.669 I\\/content_query_sample(  915): [content:\\/\\/com.android.email.provider\\/body,sourceMessageKey,messageKey=?,,115,,24]\\n11-01 16:48:52.679 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1104415000,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:48:59.069 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1105287480,com.android.vending\\/com.google.android.finsky.services.ContentSyncService,,19030]\\n11-01 16:48:59.319 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1105287480,com.android.vending\\/com.google.android.finsky.services.ContentSyncService,19030]\\n11-01 16:49:00.349 I\\/content_update_sample(19165): [content:\\/\\/com.lge.mlt.main\\/t325,insert,,168,,34]\\n11-01 16:49:07.569 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1104755864,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:49:07.599 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1104755864,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:49:09.689 I\\/free_storage_changed(  375): 2386087936\\n11-01 16:49:11.259 I\\/notification_enqueue(  375): [android,17040422,NULL,Notification(contentView=android\\/0x109009a vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x2)]\\n11-01 16:49:11.269 I\\/notification_enqueue(  375): [android,17040422,NULL,Notification(contentView=android\\/0x109009a vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x2)]\\n11-01 16:49:11.289 I\\/binder_sample(  544): [android.view.IWindowSession,4,6,com.lge.ime,1]\\n11-01 16:49:13.249 I\\/notification_cancel(  375): [android,17040422,NULL,0,0]\\n11-01 16:49:16.109 I\\/am_new_intent(  375): [1098333256,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen,NULL,NULL,NULL,0]\\n11-01 16:49:17.369 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1102976712,com.google.android.gms\\/.gcm.PushMessagingRegistrarProxy,act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms,782]\\n11-01 16:49:17.379 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1102914280,com.google.android.gms\\/.gcm.GcmRegisterService,act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms,691]\\n11-01 16:49:17.389 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1102976712,com.google.android.gms\\/.gcm.PushMessagingRegistrarProxy,782]\\n11-01 16:49:17.819 I\\/google_http_request(  691): [399,200,Android-GCM\\/1.3,1]\\n11-01 16:49:17.849 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1102914280,com.google.android.gms\\/.gcm.GcmRegisterService,691]\\n11-01 16:49:17.859 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1101438696,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_GcmIntentHandler,act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION pkg=com.caseglobal.guardcommand,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:17.869 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1101438696,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_GcmIntentHandler,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:18.109 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1097941704,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_SyncData,,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:18.179 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1101676352,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_GpsTracker,,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:18.199 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1102631712,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_GpsGet,,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:18.209 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1101676352,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.services.SVC_GpsTracker,19765]\\n11-01 16:49:18.239 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131144\\n11-01 16:49:18.239 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131085\\n11-01 16:49:18.239 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131149\\n11-01 16:49:18.309 I\\/notification_enqueue(  375): [com.android.systemui,252119,NULL,Notification(contentView=com.android.systemui\\/0x109009a vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x2)]\\n11-01 16:49:18.909 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131144\\n11-01 16:49:18.909 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131085\\n11-01 16:49:18.919 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131149\\n11-01 16:49:18.959 I\\/content_update_sample(19165): [content:\\/\\/com.lge.mlt.common\\/t007,insert,,659,,100]\\n11-01 16:49:19.019 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131144\\n11-01 16:49:19.019 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131085\\n11-01 16:49:19.029 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131149\\n11-01 16:49:19.479 I\\/am_finish_activity(  375): [1098333256,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen,app-request]\\n11-01 16:49:19.509 I\\/am_pause_activity(  375): [1098333256,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen]\\n11-01 16:49:19.579 I\\/am_on_paused_called(19765): com.caseglobal.guardcommand.ACT_LoginScreen\\n11-01 16:49:19.599 I\\/am_resume_activity(  375): [1095772464,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen]\\n11-01 16:49:19.739 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131144\\n11-01 16:49:19.739 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131085\\n11-01 16:49:19.739 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 131149\\n11-01 16:49:19.769 I\\/content_update_sample(19165): [content:\\/\\/com.lge.mlt.common\\/t007,insert,,314,,63]\\n11-01 16:49:19.959 I\\/am_on_resume_called(19765): com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen\\n11-01 16:49:20.249 I\\/activity_launch_time(  375): [1095772464,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen,34732,34732]\\n11-01 16:49:20.299 I\\/am_destroy_activity(  375): [1098333256,17,com.caseglobal.guardcommand\\/.ACT_LoginScreen,finish-imm]\\n11-01 16:49:22.589 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1104896400,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:49:22.619 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1104896400,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:49:37.629 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1100446216,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:49:37.659 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100446216,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:49:52.669 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1102225992,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:49:52.699 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1102225992,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:50:04.359 I\\/content_update_sample(19165): [content:\\/\\/com.lge.mlt.common\\/t010,insert,,211,,43]\\n11-01 16:50:07.699 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1100562512,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:50:07.739 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100562512,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:50:09.819 I\\/wifi_supplicant_state_changed(  375): 8\\n11-01 16:50:09.819 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 147462\\n11-01 16:50:09.839 I\\/wifi_supplicant_state_changed(  375): 9\\n11-01 16:50:09.839 I\\/wifi_event_handled(  375): 147462\\n11-01 16:50:18.309 I\\/notification_cancel(  375): [com.android.systemui,252119,NULL,0,0]\\n11-01 16:50:18.309 I\\/notification_cancel(  375): [com.android.systemui,252119,NULL,0,0]\\n11-01 16:50:22.739 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1103975672,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:50:22.769 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1103975672,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:50:37.769 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1100388752,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:50:37.799 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100388752,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:50:52.809 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:50:52.839 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n",
"BUILD": {
    "TIME": 1352162496000,
    "FINGERPRINT": "lge\\/m4_open_eu\\/m4:4.0.3\\/IML74K\\/lge610-V10l.20121106.094022:user\\/release-keys",
    "HARDWARE": "m4",
    "UNKNOWN": "unknown",
    "RADIO": "unknown",
    "BOARD": "7x27",
    "PRODUCT": "m4_open_eu",
    "DISPLAY": "IML74K",
    "USER": "iamjihoon.kim",
    "HOST": "LGEARND1B5",
    "DEVICE": "m4",
    "BOOTLOADER": "unknown",
    "MODEL": "LG-E610",
    "TAGS": "release-keys",
    "CPU_ABI": "armeabi-v7a",
    "VERSION": {
        "CODENAME": "REL",
        "INCREMENTAL": "lge610-V10l.20121106.094022",
        "RELEASE": "4.0.3",
        "SDK_INT": 15,
        "RESOURCES_SDK_INT": 15,
        "SDK": 15
    },
    "CPU_ABI2": "armeabi",
    "IS_DEBUGGABLE": false,
    "ID": "IML74K",
    "SERIAL": "96a874bd",
    "BRAND": "lge",
    "MANUFACTURER": "LGE",
    "TYPE": "user"
},
"DUMPSYS_MEMINFO": "Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=19965, uid=10068 without permission android.permission.DUMP\\n",
"localID": 1,
"userID": 0101,
"locationID": 999999,
"PHONE_MODEL": "LG-E610",
"STACK_TRACE": "java.lang.NullPointerException\\n\\tat com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen$8.onClick(ACT_MainScreen.java:391)\\n\\tat android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)\\n\\tat android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)\\n\\tat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)\\n\\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)\\n\\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)\\n\\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)\\n\\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)\\n\\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)\\n\\tat dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)\\n",
"DEVICE_ID": 353089057998276,
"PRODUCT": "m4_open_eu",
"APP_VERSION_NAME": "1.2.4",
"LOGCAT": "11-01 16:50:31.439 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:31.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:31.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:31.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:31.459 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f02028c\\/com.android.systemui:drawable\\/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3_fully combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataTypeIconId=0x0 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x7f02028c mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563\\n11-01 16:50:31.469 D\\/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(  465): ACTION_SIGNAL_STRENGTH_CHANGED!!!\\n11-01 16:50:33.059 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:34.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:34.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:35.269 E\\/msm7627a.gralloc(  136): ERROR FBIOGET_ESDCHECKLOOP failed\\n11-01 16:50:36.079 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:37.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:37.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:39.089 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:40.269 E\\/msm7627a.gralloc(  136): ERROR FBIOGET_ESDCHECKLOOP failed\\n11-01 16:50:40.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:40.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:42.099 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:43.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:43.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:43.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:43.459 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f02028c\\/com.android.systemui:drawable\\/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3_fully combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataTypeIconId=0x0 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x7f02028c mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563\\n11-01 16:50:43.469 D\\/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(  465): ACTION_SIGNAL_STRENGTH_CHANGED!!!\\n11-01 16:50:45.119 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:45.269 E\\/msm7627a.gralloc(  136): ERROR FBIOGET_ESDCHECKLOOP failed\\n11-01 16:50:46.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:46.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:48.129 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:49.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:49.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:49.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service\\n11-01 16:50:49.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:49.459 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f02028c\\/com.android.systemui:drawable\\/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3_fully combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataTypeIconId=0x0 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x7f02028c mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563\\n11-01 16:50:49.469 D\\/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(  465): ACTION_SIGNAL_STRENGTH_CHANGED!!!\\n11-01 16:50:50.269 E\\/msm7627a.gralloc(  136): ERROR FBIOGET_ESDCHECKLOOP failed\\n11-01 16:50:51.149 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:52.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:52.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 18 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:54.159 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:55.269 E\\/msm7627a.gralloc(  136): ERROR FBIOGET_ESDCHECKLOOP failed\\n11-01 16:50:55.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:55.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:55.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.449 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getGsmLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  465): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getLevel=4\\n11-01 16:50:55.459 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465): refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f02028c\\/com.android.systemui:drawable\\/stat_sys_wifi_signal_3_fully combinedActivityIconId=0x0 mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mDataSignalIconId=0x7f02022c mDataTypeIconId=0x0 mNoSimIconId=0x0 mWifiIconId=0x7f02028c mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080563\\n11-01 16:50:55.469 D\\/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(  465): ACTION_SIGNAL_STRENGTH_CHANGED!!!\\n11-01 16:50:57.169 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:50:58.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength before validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 -32767 -32767 -32767 -32767 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:58.439 W\\/SignalStrength(  559): SignalStrength after validate=SignalStrength: 19 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma\\n11-01 16:50:59.999 D\\/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  375): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK\\n11-01 16:51:00.009 D\\/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  375): handleTimeUpdate\\n11-01 16:51:00.189 D\\/wpa_supplicant(  656): nl80211: survey data missing!\\n11-01 16:51:00.849 D\\/DebugPowerManagerService(  375): setPowerState call from userActivity() \\n11-01 16:51:00.849 D\\/PowerManagerService(  375): setPowerState: mPowerState=0x7 newState=0x7 noChangeLights=false reason=2\\n11-01 16:51:00.979 W\\/dalvikvm(19765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd51f8)\\n11-01 16:51:00.979 E\\/ACRA    (19765): ACRA caught a NullPointerException exception for com.caseglobal.guardcommand. Building report.\\n11-01 16:51:00.989 D\\/ACRA    (19765): Using custom Report Fields\\n11-01 16:51:01.069 I\\/ACRA    (19765): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.\\n11-01 16:51:01.099 D\\/ACRA    (19765): Retrieving logcat output...\\n",
"AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE": 2385801216,
"USER_APP_START_DATE": "2013-11-01T16:48:45.000-07:00",
"CUSTOM_DATA": {

},
"BRAND": "lge",
"PACKAGE_NAME": "com.mypackage",
"ANDROID_VERSION": "4.0.3",
"APP_VERSION_CODE": 16
}]
```

And heres what Im trying so far.

```
JArray insertedCrashReports = new JArray();

MiscTools.errorProc(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, crashReports, "", null);

JArray crashReportsArray = null;

try
{
    crashReportsArray = new JArray(crashReports);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MiscTools.errorProc(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name, "CRASH REPORT JSON FORMATTING ERROR", e.Message.ToString(), null);
}

if (crashReports != null)
{

    foreach (JValue crashReport in crashReports){

        SQLTools sql = new SQLTools();
        DataTable dtResult = null;

        sql.Helper.sSPName = "spInsertCrashData";
        sql.Helper.sConnStr = "BACKUP_GUARDS";

        JObject crashConfigJO = crashReport.Children()["CRASH_CONFIGURATION"];
```

I cant seem to get the values out no matter what Ive tried so far. I know Im missing something because this is seeming to be overly complicated for such a simple operation.

Comment: What data specifically are you trying to get out of the JSON?  All of it, or just pieces?  Also, are you tied to using `JArray`/`JObject`, or would you be open to using a fixed class structure instead?

Comment: I need all of it and I would prefer just simply getting the data out of it quick and easy without creating extra classes and stuff.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045569/how-to-access-elements-of-a-jarray

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders Hey what ever floats your boat dude. I think the tag makes it easier to find but if people want answers hidden then ok.

Comment: @Jamesandresakis: did you follow the link I posted? It's not just _my_ boat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have already solved your issue, but I was going to suggest this as a possible solution.

Basically, I use a couple of helper methods to extract the data from the JSON and put it into a more digestible form-- a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.  Each `Dictionary<string, string>` represents one crash report.  The hierarchical crash data gets flattened down by concatenating the property names into a dot-separated "path".  This makes it easy to dump it out, which it looks like is your intent.  For convenience, I replace all the "\n" and "\t" strings in the data with the real equivalents.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // (Note: json test string is defined as a constant at bottom - scroll down)

        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> crashReport in GetCrashData(json))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in crashReport)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));
        }
    }

    static List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetCrashData(string json)
    {
        JArray ja = JArray.Parse(json);
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        foreach (JObject jo in ja.Children<JObject>())
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            FillDictionaryFromJObject(dict, jo, null);
            list.Add(dict);
        }
        return list;
    }

    static void FillDictionaryFromJObject(Dictionary<string, string> dict, JObject jo, string prefix)
    {
        foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
        {
            string name = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? prop.Name : prefix + "." + prop.Name);
            JToken token = prop.Value;
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                FillDictionaryFromJObject(dict, (JObject)token, name);
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(name, token.ToString()
                    .Replace("\\n", "\r\n")
                    .Replace("\\t", "\t")
                    .Replace("\\/", "/"));
            }
        }
    }

    static readonly string json = @"
    [
        {
            ""CRASH_CONFIGURATION"": {
                ""hardKeyboardHidden"": ""HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES"",
                ""orientation"": ""ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT"",
                ""keyboard"": ""KEYBOARD_NOKEYS"",
                ""screenLayout"": ""SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL+SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO"",
                ""mcc"": 310,
                ""textLayoutDirection"": 0,
                ""locale"": ""en_US"",
                ""compatScreenHeightDp"": 455,
                ""compatSmallestScreenWidthDp"": 320,
                ""fontScale"": ""1.0"",
                ""navigationHidden"": ""NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES"",
                ""screenWidthDp"": 320,
                ""fontTypeIndex"": ""-1"",
                ""screenHeightDp"": 455,
                ""uiMode"": ""UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL+UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO"",
                ""userSetLocale"": false,
                ""navigation"": ""NAVIGATION_NONAV"",
                ""smallestScreenWidthDp"": 320,
                ""keyboardHidden"": ""KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO"",
                ""seq"": 4,
                ""mnc"": 410,
                ""compatScreenWidthDp"": 320,
                ""touchscreen"": ""TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER""
            },
            ""USER_CRASH_DATE"": ""2013-11-01T16:51:01.000-07:00"",
            ""EVENTSLOG"": ""11-01 16:48:22.499 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1096405040,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:48:36.229 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1096742288,com.android.defcontainer\\/.DefaultContainerService,,19270]\\n(...snip...)\\n11-01 16:50:37.799 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100388752,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n11-01 16:50:52.809 I\\/am_create_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]\\n11-01 16:50:52.839 I\\/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email\\/.Controller$ControllerService,915]\\n"",
            ""BUILD"": {
                ""TIME"": 1352162496000,
                ""FINGERPRINT"": ""lge\\/m4_open_eu\\/m4:4.0.3\\/IML74K\\/lge610-V10l.20121106.094022:user\\/release-keys"",
                ""HARDWARE"": ""m4"",
                ""UNKNOWN"": ""unknown"",
                ""RADIO"": ""unknown"",
                ""BOARD"": ""7x27"",
                ""PRODUCT"": ""m4_open_eu"",
                ""DISPLAY"": ""IML74K"",
                ""USER"": ""iamjihoon.kim"",
                ""HOST"": ""LGEARND1B5"",
                ""DEVICE"": ""m4"",
                ""BOOTLOADER"": ""unknown"",
                ""MODEL"": ""LG-E610"",
                ""TAGS"": ""release-keys"",
                ""CPU_ABI"": ""armeabi-v7a"",
                ""VERSION"": {
                    ""CODENAME"": ""REL"",
                    ""INCREMENTAL"": ""lge610-V10l.20121106.094022"",
                    ""RELEASE"": ""4.0.3"",
                    ""SDK_INT"": 15,
                    ""RESOURCES_SDK_INT"": 15,
                    ""SDK"": 15
                },
                ""CPU_ABI2"": ""armeabi"",
                ""IS_DEBUGGABLE"": false,
                ""ID"": ""IML74K"",
                ""SERIAL"": ""96a874bd"",
                ""BRAND"": ""lge"",
                ""MANUFACTURER"": ""LGE"",
                ""TYPE"": ""user""
            },
            ""DUMPSYS_MEMINFO"": ""Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=19965, uid=10068 without permission android.permission.DUMP\\n"",
            ""localID"": 1,
            ""userID"": 101,
            ""locationID"": 999999,
            ""PHONE_MODEL"": ""LG-E610"",
            ""STACK_TRACE"": ""java.lang.NullPointerException\\n\\tat com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen$8.onClick(ACT_MainScreen.java:391)\\n\\tat android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)\\n\\tat android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)\\n\\tat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)\\n\\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)\\n\\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)\\n\\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)\\n\\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)\\n\\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)\\n\\tat dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)\\n"",
            ""DEVICE_ID"": 353089057998276,
            ""PRODUCT"": ""m4_open_eu"",
            ""APP_VERSION_NAME"": ""1.2.4"",
            ""LOGCAT"": ""11-01 16:50:31.439 D\\/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0\\n11-01 16:50:31.449 W\\/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4\\n(...snip...)\\n11-01 16:51:00.979 W\\/dalvikvm(19765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd51f8)\\n11-01 16:51:00.979 E\\/ACRA    (19765): ACRA caught a NullPointerException exception for com.caseglobal.guardcommand. Building report.\\n11-01 16:51:00.989 D\\/ACRA    (19765): Using custom Report Fields\\n11-01 16:51:01.069 I\\/ACRA    (19765): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.\\n11-01 16:51:01.099 D\\/ACRA    (19765): Retrieving logcat output...\\n"",
            ""AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE"": 2385801216,
            ""USER_APP_START_DATE"": ""2013-11-01T16:48:45.000-07:00"",
            ""CUSTOM_DATA"": {},
            ""BRAND"": ""lge"",
            ""PACKAGE_NAME"": ""com.mypackage"",
            ""ANDROID_VERSION"": ""4.0.3"",
            ""APP_VERSION_CODE"": 16
        }
    ]";

}
```

Here is the output (truncated in places, since it is rather lengthy):

```
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.hardKeyboardHidden: HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.orientation: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.keyboard: KEYBOARD_NOKEYS
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.screenLayout: SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL+SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.mcc: 310
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.textLayoutDirection: 0
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.locale: en_US
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.compatScreenHeightDp: 455
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.compatSmallestScreenWidthDp: 320
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.fontScale: 1.0
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.navigationHidden: NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.screenWidthDp: 320
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.fontTypeIndex: -1
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.screenHeightDp: 455
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.uiMode: UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL+UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.userSetLocale: False
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.navigation: NAVIGATION_NONAV
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.smallestScreenWidthDp: 320
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.keyboardHidden: KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.seq: 4
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.mnc: 410
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.compatScreenWidthDp: 320
CRASH_CONFIGURATION.touchscreen: TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER
USER_CRASH_DATE: 11/1/2013 6:51:01 PM
EVENTSLOG: 11-01 16:48:22.499 I/am_destroy_service(  375): [1096405040,com.android.email/.Controller$ControllerService,915]
11-01 16:48:36.229 I/am_create_service(  375): [1096742288,com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService,,19270]
(...snip...)
11-01 16:50:37.799 I/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100388752,com.android.email/.Controller$ControllerService,915]
11-01 16:50:52.809 I/am_create_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email/.Controller$ControllerService,,915]
11-01 16:50:52.839 I/am_destroy_service(  375): [1100623264,com.android.email/.Controller$ControllerService,915]

BUILD.TIME: 1352162496000
BUILD.FINGERPRINT: lge/m4_open_eu/m4:4.0.3/IML74K/lge610-V10l.20121106.094022:user/release-keys
BUILD.HARDWARE: m4
BUILD.UNKNOWN: unknown
BUILD.RADIO: unknown
BUILD.BOARD: 7x27
BUILD.PRODUCT: m4_open_eu
BUILD.DISPLAY: IML74K
BUILD.USER: iamjihoon.kim
BUILD.HOST: LGEARND1B5
BUILD.DEVICE: m4
BUILD.BOOTLOADER: unknown
BUILD.MODEL: LG-E610
BUILD.TAGS: release-keys
BUILD.CPU_ABI: armeabi-v7a
BUILD.VERSION.CODENAME: REL
BUILD.VERSION.INCREMENTAL: lge610-V10l.20121106.094022
BUILD.VERSION.RELEASE: 4.0.3
BUILD.VERSION.SDK_INT: 15
BUILD.VERSION.RESOURCES_SDK_INT: 15
BUILD.VERSION.SDK: 15
BUILD.CPU_ABI2: armeabi
BUILD.IS_DEBUGGABLE: False
BUILD.ID: IML74K
BUILD.SERIAL: 96a874bd
BUILD.BRAND: lge
BUILD.MANUFACTURER: LGE
BUILD.TYPE: user
DUMPSYS_MEMINFO: Permission Denial: can't dump meminfo from from pid=19965, uid=10068 without permission android.permission.DUMP

localID: 1
userID: 101
locationID: 999999
PHONE_MODEL: LG-E610
STACK_TRACE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.caseglobal.guardcommand.mainscreen.ACT_MainScreen$8.onClick(ACT_MainScreen.java:391)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

DEVICE_ID: 353089057998276
PRODUCT: m4_open_eu
APP_VERSION_NAME: 1.2.4
LOGCAT: 11-01 16:50:31.439 D/StatusBar.NetworkController(  465):  No service
11-01 16:50:31.449 W/SignalStrength(  375): charels mCountryCode: mOperatorCode EUOPEN
11-01 16:50:31.449 W/SignalStrength(  375): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 0
11-01 16:50:31.449 W/SignalStrength(  375): getGsmLevel=4
(...snip...)
11-01 16:51:00.979 W/dalvikvm(19765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd51f8)
11-01 16:51:00.979 E/ACRA    (19765): ACRA caught a NullPointerException exception for com.caseglobal.guardcommand. Building report.
11-01 16:51:00.989 D/ACRA    (19765): Using custom Report Fields
11-01 16:51:01.069 I/ACRA    (19765): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
11-01 16:51:01.099 D/ACRA    (19765): Retrieving logcat output...

AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE: 2385801216
USER_APP_START_DATE: 11/1/2013 6:48:45 PM
BRAND: lge
PACKAGE_NAME: com.mypackage
ANDROID_VERSION: 4.0.3
APP_VERSION_CODE: 16
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow extra [] brackets were being added from the client which was causing crazy stupid errors that I would never have thought to look for.

Comment: OK, glad you got it figured out.  I worked out a possible solution based the parameters you gave; figure I might as well post it.  You may not need it any more, but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks :) Its always cool to have some one through in some brain power.