# How to access a collection in C# using Newtonsoft JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a C# console app fetching json from a web api. Using Newtonsoft JSON deserialization, I successfully manage to pull the data however I can't access `data[0]` for example.

My code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    { // TODO: check if HttpWebRequest can replace WebRequest.Create
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + "cute cat" + "&api_key=...") as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Nothing";

        using (var s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                var Json = sr.ReadToEnd(); // json response from web api request
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json); // json to c# objects
                //(data.images).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                System.Console.WriteLine(data);

            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

but when trying to access `data[0]` I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.'
```

I also tried without `dynamic` with the help of json2csharp that did not work either.

Comment: Post the object which you are receiving as response

Comment: Was there anything wrong with just deserializing the json to [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object) classes?

Comment: The response is an object apparently, not an array. Specifically, it's an object that has a `data` property that's an array...

Answer (score 0):

The very short answer is [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm).

I just checked and there even are examples of how to use it here on SO, for example at [How to access elements of a JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045569/how-to-access-elements-of-a-jarray#16045808)

**However**, since you didn't provide the data that is being de-serialized it's impossible to say if JArray is the answer for your problem.

Comment: He actually had the request url in the question so technically it is possible for us to see how the response looks like. Though that should be in the question itself.

Comment: im a female guys !

Comment: @Eva: Sorry, my apologies. Admittedly, I don't pay too much attention to names until I need to respond directly to the person.

Answer (score 0):

The response is an object that has a `data` property to an array. You cannot access properties of an object using integers, only strings.

You should pay attention to what the response actually looks like, don't guess.

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json);
foreach (var data in response.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.images);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var dataList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassModel>>(data.ToString());
```

`ClassModel` should be a class equivalent to the object which is being sent as response from the api.