# C# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid for JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I tried to print all of the sub keys in "items" from json file(shown below), but getting an invalid cast exception on this line:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sub in (JObject)obj2["items"])
```

I have no idea why it keeps showing this error.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;


public class JsonReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string filePath;

    [ContextMenu("Load Data")]
    private void LoadData()
    {
        JObject obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sub in (JObject)obj2["items"])
        {

            Debug.Log(sub.Key);
        }
    }   
}
```

JSON File Content

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "143675",
            "item": "Action Figure",
            "name": "Goku",
            "color": "Orange"
        },
        {
            "id": "258943",
            "item": "Water Bottle",
            "name": "Pcares",
            "color": "Silver"
        },
        {
            "id": "326824",
            "item": "White Board",
            "name": "Boardy",
            "color": "White"
        },
        {
            "id": "423168",
            "item": "Monitor",
            "name": "Dell",
            "color": "Black"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the expected output to show all of the keys so like:

```
id
item
name
color
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd say that obj2["items"] is a JArray, so it cannot be cast to a JObject? and you would need a foreach(JObject object in (Jarray)obj2["items"]) first followed by looping through the keys? [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045569/how-to-access-elements-of-a-jarray)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely, the value under the key `items` is an array:

```
"items": [ // <--- square bracket!
    {
        "id": "143675",
        "item": "Action Figure",
        "name": "Goku",
        "color": "Orange"
    },
```

The keys you want to get are in the elements in the array. Assuming that there will always be items in the array, you can do:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sub in (JObject)obj2["items"][0])
```

Notice the `[0]` at the end. This gets the first item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject should be your domain class type to map the properties.

Example:

```
  public class MyItem
  {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Item { get; set; }
  }
```

But be careful: property names and json names case sensitive should be equal

Comment: That doesn't answer why the current code fails though. While it's often useful to create a domain class, it's not *required*.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `KeyValuePair<string, JToken>` in `foreach`

But beware that `KeyValuePair` is used while deserializing JSON when your JSON have `key` : `value` pair like

```
{
  "ABC" : {
      "X" : "x",
      "Y" : "y",
      "Z" : "z"
  }
}
```

In above json `ABC` is a `Key` in `KeyValuePair` and whole object associated to ABC is an 
`Value` of `ABC` key.

**But**

Your json slightly different than above, means you have an array of objects associated with `items` key

And you are using `(JObject)obj2["items"]` that means you are iterate over `items` array but inside `items` array there is no key/value pair exist, only objects have

So far you need to use something like below,

```
foreach (JObject jObject in (JArray)obj2["items"])
{
    Debug.Log(jObject["id"].ToString());
    Debug.Log(jObject["item"].ToString());
    Debug.Log(jObject["name"].ToString());
    Debug.Log(jObject["color"].ToString());
}
```

By this way you can retrieve all the objects inside your `items` array

Answer (score 0):

You have written `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sub in (JObject)obj2["items"])`

here `obj2["items"]` is of `JArray` type and not `JObject`

The `invalidCastException` is because you are trying to cast a `JArray` type of object to `JObject` in the `foreach` statement.

Going by what you want to achieve ultimately, it seems that you have written everything correctly but missed to add `[0]` at the end of `(JObject)obj2["items"]`

So the correct `foreach` statement would be:

`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> sub in (JObject)obj2["items"][0]) // you missed to add this [0] in your code`